# Naming fabric operations

Tags: python, naming-conventions, naming, fabric

I often notice fabfiles in different projects having functions like below

- install_ngnix
- setup_ngnix
- deploy_ngnix

My interpretation/naming preference is install_* for package install tasks but setup_* and deploy_* sounds very similar perhaps overlapping.

I wonder what is generally accepted and better practice? And what does above names would mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any *accepted* practice for naming such things, but here is what the different names mean to me in case this is any help:

- **install_nginx**: This suggests the function is actually taking the nginx package from an external repository and installing it onto the server.
- **setup_nginx**: This suggests that nginx is already installed, and you are setting it up for your specific purposes, for example deploying your own nginx configuration files.
- **deploy_nginx**: This suggests that nginx is a software package that you own, and you are deploying it to the server (note the subtle difference to install, where install suggests a software package managed by someone else).

To be honest I think either of these names would work, but must say I admire your focus on trying to get your naming spot on.

Comment: I tend to agree with your interpretation of install and setup. To me Deploy more sounds like making nginx ready for you setup which also involves invoking install() and setup().

Answer (score 1):

Here's my insight (I use `fabric` in almost all of my projects but I'm not that experienced in it).

As soon as you realize that your `fabfile` is too big and not really readable with that `install_nginx`, `restart_apache`, `backup_db`, `create_virtualenv`, `configure_permissions` tasks - you should consider making it better.

1. use `fabfile` package instead of a single script.
2. define a submodule for every component you have to deal, e.g. `database`, `nginx`, `virtualenv` etc.
3. in each of these submodules define related tasks. E.g. for `nginx` submodule in your case it might be `install`, `setup`, `deploy`.
4. in the `__init__.py` define high-level tasks like `build`, `deploy`, `restart` that make use of and call subtasks for other components.

Sample `fabfile` package structure:

```
fabfile
├── __init__.py
├── db.py
└── nginx.py
```

Then the output of `fab --list` would be smth like this:

```
deploy
build
setup
db.backup
nginx.setup
nginx.install
nginx.deploy
```

Also see relevant [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/tasks.html#namespaces).

Hope that helps.